# Search for project in Forge BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have over 3000 projects in our BIM 360 account and need to be able to search for a specific project by name. Currently we are using the GET projects endpoint in the Forge BIM 360 API to create a list of projects and querying the list to find the project. This was working well for a while, but due to a limit of 100 projects returned by the endpoint we have to make multiple calls using the offset parameter. With 3000 projects this requires 30 requests, and we are starting to see a performance hit in some of our applications, which will only get worse over time as we add more projects. Is there a way to call the GET projects endpoint with a filter on project name?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can call `/project/v1/hubs/:hub_id/projects` with `page[limit]=200`, but unfortunate we don't have a filter *by name*.